# Multiple index searches

Tags: vb.net

I have written a code to search for text using the index to not save to the listbox.
I need to add more characters to search.
I need to find the text starting with  - and at the end -> this text is not written to the listbox.
They also need to find text beginning with / ** and at the end of * / but this code no longer works.

```
Dim openfile = New OpenFileDialog() With {.Filter = "Text (*.php)|*.php"}
If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(openfile.FileName, Encoding.Default)
        'OPEN DIALOG
    Next

End If

Dim komentar As Boolean

komentar = False
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(openfile.FileName, Encoding.Default)
    'FIND Charakter <!- and stop write to listbox
    If Not line.IndexOf("<!-") = -1 Then
        komentar = True
    End If

    If komentar Then --- this wrong
    'FIND Charakter --> and afrer write to listbox  
    If Not line.IndexOf("-->") = -1 Then
        komentar = False
    End If
    ' I don't know how to specify another condition to search for other sentences 
    ' that don't write when it finds characters
    If Not line.IndexOf("/**") = -1 Then
        komentar = True
    End If

    If komentar Then
        If Not line.IndexOf("*/") = -1 Then
            komentar = False
        End If
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
    End If
```

This code has the task of opening a file through a dialog box. Before it is loaded into the list box, it searches for text that begins with / ** and ends with * / and this text is not written to the listbox. I still need the listbox not to include sentences starting with  so I used if not line.indexof and comment True or False.

Comment: *"this code no longer works"*.  That is never an acceptable description. You must provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which includes the exact behaviour of the code and how that differs from your expectation.  Also, what's up with that crazy indenting?  There's no excuse for making code hard to read when the IDE can format it for you.  If you can't make a small effort to help us then it's less likely that we'll be inclined to make the effort to help you.

Comment: i am editing ask I don't know how to write it better

Comment: `Not line.IndexOf("<!-") = -1` should be `line.IndexOf("<!-") >= 0` to make it simpler to understand, and that can be further simplified to `line.Contains("<!-")` (because there is no case-sensitivity to worry about with those characters). If you change all of the lines like that then you might find it easier to see if the logic is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your request at first but Andrew Morton's comment made me realise what you were actually asking for.  Here's how I might implement it:

```
Dim terminatorsByInitiator As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"<!--", "-->"},
                                                                      {"/**", "*/"}}
Dim isComment = False
Dim terminator As String

For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(openfile.FileName, Encoding.Default)
    If isComment Then
        'Check whether we are at the end of the comment.
        If line.EndsWith(terminator) Then
            isComment = False
        End If
    Else
        'Get the comment initiator at the start of the line, if there is one.
        Dim initiator = terminatorsByInitiator.Keys.FirstOrDefault(Function(s) line.StartsWith(s))

        If initiator Is Nothing Then
            'This line does not initiate a comment so add it to the list.
            ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
        Else
            'This line does initiate a comment.
            isComment = True

            'Remember which comment terminator to look for.
            terminator = terminatorsByInitiator(initiator)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The use of the `Dictionary` ensures that you always look for the right comment terminator based on the initiator that was found.

Comment: I have a suspicion that `/*` and `*/` are for multiline comments.

Comment: Yes comments / ** and * / can also be <! - -> on one or more lines. I used just wanted indexof. What Andrew Morton writes will make me only a comment in the listbox <! - -> but everything else is not written and I need it the other way around. –

Comment: Option Strict complained that `line` is Object.

Comment: `terminator` has not been assigned a value?

Comment: @Mary, you'd only have an issue with `Option Strict On` if you had `Option Infer Off`.  `File.ReadAllLines` returns a `String` array so `line` will be inferred to be type `String`.

Comment: @Mary, there's no issue with `terminator` not being initialised because, if you follow the logic, the only time the value of `terminator` is used is if `isComment` is `True` and the the only place `isComment` is set to `True`, a value is also assigned to `terminator`.  You may get a warning about it, because the compiler won't be able to work out that that is the case, so the solution is to explicitly initialise `terminator` to `Nothing`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for explanation. I had Option Infer On but I needed to add a line `Dim openfile As New OpenFileDialog`. Then all was well.